# Leading zero if number is lower than 10 - bug with number 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating some kind of JS clocks where real life minute == 1 clock's hour. But there is one bug, every number in minutes which is lower than 10 is rewritten to `"0"+minute`, so it looks like 01, 02 and etc. but there is a problem with number 0, it's output is 0, not 00 as I wanted, here is my code.

```
// time and date
var minute = 57;
var hour = 0;

function getTime(){
    $("#time").html(hour+":"+minute);
};
function init(){
    setInterval(function(){getTime();}, 1000);
    setInterval(function(){
        if (minute == 59){
            hour=++hour;
            minute=minute-59;           // (\(\    Hoo hoo
        }                               // ( . .)  you found
        else {                          // c(“)(“) a bunny :)
            minute=++minute;
            if (minute < 10){
                minute="0"+minute;
            } 
        } 
    }, 1000);
}
init();
```

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: Are you sure about it? This bunny always protects my code. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `minute = 0` in `if` block, not `else`.

Just replace `minute=minute-59` with `minute = '00'`, because that's only one case when you'll enter that `if` (`minute` must be equal to `59` and then you're subtracting `59` from it, so it'll be always 0).

Comment: But `if (minute < 10){
                minute="0"+minute;
            } ` is checking that.

Comment: @Kyrbi No, because you'll never reach that `if`. To do that, `minute` have to be different than 59, but you are setting `minute` to 0 only when `minute` is 59. So it'll never happen :)

Comment: I tried it with that "00" but it created another bug (classic), it does show 00 as I want but 01, 02...09 arent working.

Comment: @Kyrbi Can you create fiddle with modified code? I just checked it in JS console and it worked well.

Comment: It works, I had typo in my code, sorry. :) Thank you for your help, it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
 $("#time").html(hour+":"+("00"+minute).slice(-2));
```

and remove the concatenation where you're incrementing the `minute`

Answer (score 0):

```
hour = hour.toString();
minute = minute.toString();
while (hour.length < 2) hour = "0" + hour;
while (minute.length < 2) minute = "0" + minute;
```